# Why can't static_cast a double void pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

Consider the following piece of code:

```
void **v_dptr(nullptr);
int  **i_dptr = static_cast<int**>(v_dptr);
```

The above example produces the following compile error:

> `static_cast from 'void **' to 'int **' is not allowed`

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/030b91e0406120b4)

I know that the proper way to cast a `void` pointer to any other pointer type is to use `static_cast`. However, you can't `static_cast` a double `void` pointer to another double pointer of other type.

### Q:

1. Why we can't `static_cast` a double `void` pointer?
2. What's the proper way to cast a double `void` pointer?

Comment: The same problem comes up with integer types. You can `static_cast` an `int` to a `long`. You cannot `static_cast` an `int *` to a `long *`, even on implementations where `int` and `long` have the same representation and alignment. Do you think you should be able to do that on those implementations? If not, why not?

Comment: How did `void**` appear in your code in first place?

Comment: @AntonSavin Legacy C code, I don't like it either, but I have to deal with it :(.

Comment: @40two so this thing is returned by some C function, or it's a parameter passed to some function?

Comment: @AntonSavin Actually an attempt of the "elders" to create a generic array of pointers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have a `void*` and cast it to an `int*`, there may or may not be some mathematical/width adjustment to create an instance of the proper type, which `static_cast<>` will be prepared to do.  When you have only a pointer to a `void*` and want a pointer to an `int*`, the `static_cast<>` has no write access to the pointed-to `void*` object; it is not free to adjust it to make sure it's a valid `int*` such that the `static_cast<>` can succeed and return a pointer which really can be used to access a valid `int*`.  While on some architectures this may not matter, if the standard allowed this then the code could break when ported.  (Keep in mind that it's unreasonable to expect the `static_cast<>` to arrange for some additional memory for an `int*` somewhere that it initialises using a `static_cast<int*>(the_void_ptr)` - not only would that have unexpected overheads, but it'd need to be in thread specific memory or allocated dynamically and released somehow, and all manner of code that actually ends up comparing the pointer values would break.)

If you want to force the matter and promise the compiler that the width of both types is the same and no mathematical adjustment is necessary etc. - then you can use `reinterpret_cast<>` and boss it around, making it clear you're accepting the risk of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

`void*` is special in that it can point to anything. It is a "pointer to unspecified type." Therefore, converting to and from `void*` to `T*` for some type `T` is a "normal" operation, one which `static_cast` can support. In effect, such a conversion says: "The pointer doesn't know to what it points, but I know it: it points to a `T`."

`void**` is not special special in this way. It can point to one thing only, to a `void*`. Converting a `void**` to an `int**` says something different: "The pointer claims it points to a `void*`, but I want to treat it as a pointer to `int*` instead." And if you want to treat one thing as a different thing, you want to *reinterpret* the original - so use `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is an XY-problem. Depending on the circumstances it can be solved without `reinterpret_cast`. If you know that the `void**` pointer in fact points to a pointer to `int`, you can safely do this:

```
int* iptr = static_cast<int*>(*v_dptr);
```

Unless you really need `int**` in your code. And if you need, you can do:

```
int** i_dptr = &iptr;
```

but beware that it will point to a local variable `iptr` which will be destroyed when goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

There are good answers for Q1, and the answer to Q2 depends a lot on the intention. If `void **v_dptr` is intended to be a pointer to a "generic" `void*` which you know is actually a `int*` and you want to cast accordingly, the following might be what you want:

```
int *i_ptr = static_cast<int*>(*v_dptr);
int **i_dptr = &i_ptr;
```

Comment: This is a *DRASTICALLY* changed behaviour:


you might want to do something like:

*v_dptr=malloc(1024);
=> v_dptr will be modified (holding a pointer to a buffer of 1024 byte)

But after your cast, this has changed:
*i_dptr =malloc(1024);
v_dptr is unmodified.
i_ptr will be your new buffer.

Comment: @DThought `This is a DRASTICALLY changed behaviour` Changed from what? OP's example has no behaviour because it doesn't compile. `*v_dptr=malloc(1024); => v_dptr will be modified` That will modify `*v_dptr`, not `v_dptr`.  `*i_dptr =malloc(1024)` This doesn't compile due to invalid types. `v_dptr is unmodified. i_ptr will be your new buffer.` (If you fix the type error,) The behavirou is the same as in your first example: `v_dptr`/`i_dptr` remain unmodified. `*v_dptr`/`*i_dptr`/`i_ptr` are modified.

Answer (score 1):

A `static_cast` can do the reverse of any implicit conversion.

There is an implicit conversion `int*` → `void*`; it doesn't do more than lose the information about the type of the pointed to object.

There is no implicit conversion `int**` → `void**`. If it was allowed it would *reinterpret* the object pointer to, namely, reinterpreting an `int*` as a `void*`. On some old architectures an `int*` did not necessarily have as large a value representation as a `void*` (or `char*`, the pointer types with the least alignment requirements).

The reinterpretation requires a `reinterpret_cast`.

IMHO it's a good idea to use `reinterpret_cast` *in general* for conversions to/from `void*`, because that communicates intent to the reader. However, as I recall Sutter and Alexandrescu recommended using `static_cast`, presumably due to a lack of a formal guarantee in C++03. Also as I recall, that purely formal problem was fixed in C++11.