# Why do I Have to reinterpret_cast Pointer Pointers?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, static-cast, double-pointer

So this `static_cast` code is totally legal:

```
int n = 13;
void* pn = static_cast<void*>(&n);
void** ppn = &pn;
```

Yet this has to be made into a `reinterpret_cast` to compile:

```
int n = 13;
int* foo = &n;
void** bar = static_cast<void**>(&foo);
```

If I don't change it I get the error:

> error C2440: `static_cast`: cannot convert from `int **` to `void **`
>   note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires `reinterpret_cast`, C-style cast or function-style cast

So I take it the issue is "the types are unrelated". Yet I still don't understand, if it's OK when going from an `int*` to `void*` how can they be unrelated as a `int**` and a `void**`?

Comment: why is your second snippet striked through?

Comment: You could see `&foo` as a *pointer to `int*`*, and `bar` is a *pointer to `void*`*. Those two types are very different. It's the extra level of indirection which makes the whole difference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't static\_cast a double void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277391/why-cant-static-cast-a-double-void-pointer)

Comment: Note that it is not even guaranteed that `sizeof (int*)` and `sizeof (void*)` are the same

Comment: @user463035818 It gives the error in the question. Just didn't want to give the appearance that it was functional code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yikes... what? I thought pointers were the same size?

Comment: its very hard to read. Questions typically have erroneous code, its hard to miss when the next line says "...I get the error". I never copy code from questions but rather from answers....

Comment: @user463035818 \*shrug\* I'll remove it if you think so. I just wanted it to be clear.

Comment: @JonathanMee: Your particular platform may guarantee that all object pointers are the same size and representation, but that's a non-portable assumption.  (The guarantee is in fact very popular, since it's part of the POSIX standard... but older architectures and bare metal systems do otherwise and still are C++ compliant)

Comment: @JonathanMee Another approach that is easier to read is to add a comment on the line which raises the diagnostic.

Comment: @BenVoigt So... how would this even work? I thought there was a requirement that anything could be cast to and from a `void*`? If a `void*` were of a different size wouldn't that nullify this requirement?

Comment: @JonathanMee no. As long as `void*` is big enough to uniquely represent any pointer value, it can work. There is no reason why a `T*` couldn't be smaller than `void*`.

Comment: @JonathanMee: The round-trip requirement can be satisfied if pointers without alignment requirements (`void*` and `char*`) are bigger than pointers with alignment requirements (including `int*`).

Comment: Meanwhile other popular platforms take advantage of the fact that aligned pointers don't store any address information in the lowest bits by reusing those bits for other purposes, for example function pointers on ARM use one bit to indicate the target function uses the Thumb instruction set.

Comment: @BenVoigt OK, I'm totally off topic here. Would you prefer to answer this in a new question? I can open one if you prefer. But how would I even use something like [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) in such a system; say I was trying to stream out an array, how could I even know that `void*` had the same stride?

Comment: `static_cast<void*>` isn't even an explicit conversion, it's an implicit conversion done explicitly

Comment: @JonathanMee: Why would `fwrite` care about the stride of `void*`? (Like 303's answer says, there actually isn't one, pointer math with `void*` is illegal)  Are you trying to write an array of void pointers `void* a[]`?  You can do that, but the resulting file won't be portable.  Pointer values only have meaning in the same address space, even reading the file on the exact same system after restarting will be useless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int` is in no way related to `void`. The same goes for `int**` and `void**` and so they cannot be converted using `static_cast`.

`void*` however, is **special**. Any data pointer type (including `int*`) can be `static_cast` into `void*` and back, despite no type being related to `void` (even further, the conversion to `void*` doesn't need a cast, as it is implicit). `int*` doesn't have this property, nor does `void**` and nor does any other pointer besides `void*`.

---

The additional freedoms that have been granted to `void*` come with additional restrictions. `void*` cannot be indirected, nor can it be used with pointer arithmetic. These restrictions are only possible because there can never be an object of type `void`. Or from opposite point of view, objects of `void` cannot exist because of these restrictions.

`void**` cannot be given those freedoms, because it cannot be given the same restrictions. It cannot be given those restrictions because `void*` objects do exist and they need to exist. If we couldn't indirect or iterate `void**`, then we couldn't use arrays of `void*` for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
void* pn = static_cast<void*>(&n);
```

is an implicit conversion; you can also write

```
void *pn = &n;
```

It means that `pn` stores a pointer to some object type; the programmer is responsible for knowing what that object type is. To cast back you need a `static_cast`:

```
int *pi = static_cast<int*>(pn);
```

Note that using `static_cast` to cast to any type significantly different than the original (`float` is significantly different, `const int` isn't) is a way of doing a reinterpretation. You should spell that `reinterpret_cast` not implicit conversion (or `static_cast`) followed by `static_cast`.

This is the whole purpose of `void*`, an concept tracing back to C, where casts are spelled with C-style casts obviously (not `static_cast`...) but have otherwise identical meanings.

**Going back to the syntax of declarations in C and C++:**

The declaration of a pointer to `int` is `int (*pi);` (parentheses are useless but help illustrate the point), you can read it like: I declare that expression `(*pi)` has type `int`. You can read a function declaration that way: in `int f(int i);` I declare that if `i` has type `int` then `f(i)` has type `int`.

The declaration `void (*pi);` looks like a pointer to a `void` but there is no such thing as an object of type `void`, the expression `*pi` isn't even well formed, it doesn't make sense. It's a **special case** in the type system: the syntax says "pointer to void", semantic says "pointer to something".

In C and C++, a pointer object is a first class object and you can take its address and have a pointer to a pointer, etc. (Contrast with Java where references like other fundamental types aren't class objects.)

So you can have a `int**`, `int***`... pointers to (pointers ... to `int`); you can have for the same reason `void**`: declared like a pointer to (pointer to void), semantically a pointer to (pointer to something).

Just like a pointer to `int` can't be assigned to a pointer to `float` without a cast:

```
float *f = &i; // ill-formed
```

because of the type mismatch, a type different from `void**` can't be assigned to a `void**`: **the result of dereferencing a `void**` must be a `void*` object**.

Comment: Interestingly, `reinterpret_cast` between pointer types is actually defined as having the same result as a conversion to `void*` then `static_cast`.