# reference and pointer typecasting in C++

Tags: c++, stl

I am able to typecast reference of `vector<void*>` to reference of `vector<Foo*>` whereas I am unable to typecast `vector<void*> to vector<Foo*>`. I am getting the error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>' why?

And I am able to typecast void* to Foo* without getting compiler error.

```
void* g =&foo;
reportFooVector2(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(g));
```

Below is my entire code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
  string s;
  int i;
};


void reportFooVector( vector <Foo*> * pvf )
{

}


void reportFooVector1( vector <Foo*> pvf )
{
}

void reportFooVector2( Foo *pvf )
{
}


int main()
{
    struct Foo foo = {"foo",  5};
    struct Foo goo = {"goo", 10};
    void* g =&foo;
    reportFooVector2(reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(g));
    vector <void *> vf;
    vf.push_back(&foo);
    vf.push_back(&goo);
    reportFooVector1( reinterpret_cast< vector < Foo * >  >(vf));
    reportFooVector( reinterpret_cast< vector < Foo * > * >(&vf));
}
```

In the above program I am getting the compiler *error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty>'* when calling the line `reportFooVector1( reinterpret_cast< vector < Foo * >  >(vf));`

Could you please anyone tell the reason for it?

Comment: the is an exception for `void*` that says it is allowed to be cast to and from any other pointer type. There is no such exception for `std::vector<void*>`

Comment: The reason is that it's not allowed in C++. An lvalue expression can only be reintepret_cast-ed to a ***reference*** to a type, unless the lvalue expression is a pointer, an integer, and enumeration, etc... Since a vector is neither, the only thing a vector can be reinterpret_casted is a reference.

Comment: Those are pointers, not references. Not a nitpick, since C++ has actual references and those are distinct types from pointers. Best to get terms correct to avoid confusion.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik seems a perfect answer to me, why post it in a comment ?

Comment: Why are you storing a vector of void* pointers in the first place?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Doesn't this violate strict aliasing? `vector<void*>` and `vector<foo*>` are different (unrelated?) types, right? I've even read that `void*`s and `foo*`s may be a different size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449090/why-do-i-have-to-reinterpret-cast-pointer-pointers#comment91841719_52449090

Comment: @JonathanMee - The cast is never a strict aliasing violation. It's only using the result pointer/reference for access that violates strict aliasing.

Comment: `vf.push_back(&goo);`
Here you send pointer to pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller Right of course, but presuming that the `vector<foo*>` will be used in the not toy example this is invalid.

Comment: @PaulBelanger - Hi,

 In my application I have subclassed CMFClistCtrl. I have common function OnLvnGetdispinfo() and common vector to load data and I am using this list control object in many files.

Comment: If you subclass CMFClistCtrl, then why not just use a `vector<CMFClistCtrl*>`?

Answer (score 0):

First at a high level what does [`reinterpret_cast`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/#reinterpret_cast) do?

> - Converts any pointer type to any other pointer type, even of unrelated classes
> - Cast pointers to or from integer types

Note that everything done here involves casting between, to, or from pointer types. So it's important to note that `reinterpret_cast<vector<Foo*>>(vf)` is not valid, as it casts a `vector<void*>` to a `vector<Foo*>`. All though these are `vector`s that *contain* pointers, neither `vf` nor `vector<Foo*>` is itself a pointer.

Having addressed this lets discuss `reinterpret_cast<vector<Foo*>*>(&vf)` this is *also* will result in undefined behavior if it is dereferenced because of the rules on [Type Aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).
Given that the input to the `reinterpret_cast` is DynamicType and the output is AliasedType the `reinterpret_cast` is valid only if:

> - AliasedType and DynamicType are similar
> - AliasedType is the (possibly cv-qualified) signed or unsigned variant of DynamicType
> - AliasedType is `std::byte`, `char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes
>
> Informally, two types are similar if, ignoring top-level cv-qualification:
>
> - They are the same type
> - They are both pointers, and the pointed-to types are similar
> - They are both pointers to member of the same class, and the types of the pointed-to members are similar
> - They are both arrays of the same size or both arrays of unknown bound, and the array element types are similar

Since none of these are true with respect to `vector<void*>*` and `vector<Foo*>*` dereferencing the output of this `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behavior.

---

Now that we've discussed why these are both undesirable; let me suggest that you instead do: `void reportFooVector(void** pvf, const size_t count)` You can call this by doing: `reportFooVector(data(vf), size(vf))` Internally to `reportFooVector` you'd need to cast individual elements to `Foo*`s in order to operate on them.